# Java. Extracting character from array that isn't ASCII

Tags: java

I'm trying to extract a certain character from a buffer that isn't ASCII. I'm reading in a file that contains movie names that have some non ASCII character sprinkled in it like so.

```
1|Tóy Story (1995)
2|GoldenEye (1995)
3|Four Rooms (1995)
4|Gét Shorty (1995)
```

I was able to pick off the lines that contained the non ASCII characters, but I'm trying to figure out how to get that particular character from the lines that have said non ASCII character and replace it with an ACSII character from the map I've made.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashMap<Character, Character>Char_Map = new HashMap<>();
        Char_Map.put('o','ó');
        Char_Map.put('e','é');
        Char_Map.put('i','ï');

        for(Map.Entry<Character,Character> entry: Char_Map.entrySet())
        {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " -> "+ entry.getValue());
        }

        try
        {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("movie-names.txt"));
            String contentLine= br.readLine();


            while(contentLine != null)
            {
                String[] contents = contentLine.split("\\|");
                boolean result = contents[1].matches("\\A\\p{ASCII}*\\z");

                if(!result)
                {
                    System.out.println(contentLine);

                    

                    //System.out.println();
                }

                contentLine= br.readLine();

            }
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            System.out.println("Cannot open file as it doesn't exist");
        }
    }
}
```

I tried using something along the lines of:

```
if((contentLine.charAt(i) == something
```

But I'm not sure.

Comment: FYI: [*Remove Accents and Diacritics From a String in Java*](https://www.baeldung.com/java-remove-accents-from-text) by baeldung.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `replaceAll`. Put this in the `while` loop, so that it works on each line you read from the file. With this change, you won't need the `split` and `if (... matches)` anymore.

```java
contentLine.replaceAll("ó", "o");
contentLine.replaceAll("é", "e");
contentLine.replaceAll("ï", "i");
```

If you want to keep a map, just iterate over its keys and replace with the values you want to map to:

```java
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("ó", "o");
// ... and all the others
```

Later, in your loop reading the contents, you replace all the characters:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet())
{
    String oldChar = entry.getKey();
    String newChar = entry.getValue();
    contentLine = contentLine.replaceAll(oldChar, newChar);
}
```

Here is a complete example:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HashMap<String, String> nonAsciiToAscii = new HashMap<>();
        nonAsciiToAscii.put("ó", "o");
        nonAsciiToAscii.put("é", "e");
        nonAsciiToAscii.put("ï", "i");

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("movie-names.txt"));
        String contentLine = br.readLine();
        while (contentLine != null)
        {
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : nonAsciiToAscii.entrySet())
            {
                String oldChar = entry.getKey();
                String newChar = entry.getValue();
                contentLine = contentLine.replaceAll(oldChar, newChar);
            }

            System.out.println(contentLine); // or whatever else you want to do with the cleaned lines

            contentLine = br.readLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
robert:~$ javac Main.java && java Main
1|Toy Story (1995)
2|GoldenEye (1995)
3|Four Rooms (1995)
4|Get Shorty (1995)
robert:~$
```

Comment: hmm. perhaps because my file is encoded with ISO 8859 1 it doesn't work?

Comment: Perhaps. Try passing the charset to the `FileReader` like this: `new FileReader("movie-names.txt", java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)`. In the long term I'd convert to UTF8 though.

Comment: Wait, I think I got it. Not entirely sure how though. I decided to compile in the command line and ran it and worked! Thank you very much mate.

Answer (score 0):

You want to flip your keys and values:

```
Map<Character, Character> charMap = new HashMap<>();
charMap.put('ó','o');
charMap.put('é','e');
charMap.put('ï','i');
```

and then get the mapped character:

```
char mappedChar = charMap.getOrDefault(inputChar, inputChar);
```

To get the chars for a string, call `String#toCharArray()`